# Does the Resourceful Leader multi-class Warlord feat apply to all damage rolls?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, warlord

Does the `Resourceful Leader` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2547)] multi-class `Warlord` feat apply to all damage rolls?

i.e. is that a +3 on each hit from every attack?

> **Benefit:** You gain training in one skill from the warlord’s class skills list.
>   When an ally you can see spends an action point to make an attack, the ally gains a +3 bonus to damage rolls on a hit or gains 3 temporary hit points on a miss. This bonus increases to +5 at 11th level and +7 at 21st level. These temporary hit points increase to 5 at 11th level and 7 at 21st level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If an action point was used to activate the power the attack is part of.**

If an action point is used for a multi-attack power, such as `Twin Strike`, or an AoE power, such as `Swordburst`, every *damage roll* gains the damage bonus. However, the power does not count as a *miss* unless it misses **every** target.

For example, if you use `Swordburst` while 3 enemies are adjacent to you, and hit 2 of the 3 foes, you would do +X damage (based on the warlord's level) to both foes, but you would *not* gain any temporary HP.

More examples, with `Twin Strike`:

- both hit => +X damage on each
- one hit => +X damage on that hit
- neither hit => gain X temp HP

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

As per the text you quoted, the ally must have spent an action point to get an extra action (**Rules Compendium** 235), and then used *that* action to make an attack. Only then, and only on that attack, does the ally get the bonus damage or compensatory hit points.

Comment: Ok, got that it's the single action granted by the Action Point ... but would they get a +3 for each roll in the attack *(thinking Twin Strike)*, or even each dice *(thinking a Maul being 2D6)* ?

Comment: @SteveC Yes to `Twin Strike` (each successful hit gets its own damage roll); no to the individual dice in a maul attack (that would end up as 2d6+3, not 1d6+3 twice).